# How to make the AuthUI close after successful sign in in Android Firebase Passwordless Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I'm using firebase passwordless authentication using email links. I am initiating the authentication flow as follows from a fragment:

```
ActionCodeSettings actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings.newBuilder()
            .setAndroidPackageName(/* myPackageName= */,/* installIfNotAvailable= */true, /* minimumVersion= */ null)
            .setHandleCodeInApp(true)
            .setUrl("my url")
            .setDynamicLinkDomain("my dynamic link domain")
            .build();

 // Create and launch sign-in intent
    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().enableEmailLinkSignIn()
                                    .setActionCodeSettings(actionCodeSettings).build()))
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN);
```

The authentication is working fine but upon completion, if the user clicks the back button, it takes them back to the activity that shows "Sign-in email sent". My onBackPressed() calls finish() on MainActivity. How do I make it so that clicking the back button after signing in does not display that sign-in screen?

I am catching the deep link in a different activity. Could this be the reason for this behavior?